# Is there a way to pass an Arraylist from a Controller class to Javascript in a JSP page in a Spring Application?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList of objects from a controller class to an array in Javascript when a particular `@RequestMapping` value in the mapping controller is called. Typically if I wanted to print the contents of the ArrayList from the java side I would use `model.addAttribute("events", events);` like below and have a `c:foreach` loop with `c:out` to print the values on the `welcome` page when the `/` or `welcome` mapping route is called. However, I want to store the objects in an array in javascript instead and I'm finding little information online about doing this within a Spring Framework.

I want to do this as the objects contain latitude and longitude values that I plan to use to print to print markers on a map. Any suggestions?

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(Model model) {

       ArrayList<Event> events = seeEvents.getAllEvents();
       System.out.println(events);

       model.addAttribute("events", events);

    return "welcome";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either you create an API that serve events in json  and you use an "ajax call" in your application to get it

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/events", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Event> events() {
    return seeEvents.getAllEvents();
}
```

And on (modern) javascript:

```
fetch("/myContext/events").then(function(response) {
    return response.json().then(function(json) {
        // Do your thing...
});
```

another possibility is just to set in your JSP a code to create a static array:

```
var events=[<c:forEach ...>"<c:out ...>",</c:forEach>];
```